# redirect domain.com/givenresource/givenid to domain.com/givenresource.php_ID=givenid

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Looking for assistance rewriting a URL. When a program/user requests:

```
example.com/givenresource/givenid
```

I'd like to rewrite the request to :

```
example.com/givenresource.php_ID=givenid
```

Also looking to rewrite:

```
example.com/givenresource/?searchparam=searchforthis&searchparam2=searchforthis2
```

to

```
example.com/givenresource.php?searchparam=searchforthis&searchparam2=searchforthis2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> `/givenresource/givenid` to `/givenresource.php_ID=givenid`

I assume that the `?` omission is just a typo and it should be `/givenresource.php?_ID=givenid` and `ID` is uppercase. Other assumptions:

- `givenresource` is variable and is restricted to the characters `a-z` (lowercase) and `-`.
- `givenid` is variable and is numeric, containing just the characters `0-9`.

In which case try the following in your `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?_ID=$2 [L]
```

> `/givenresource/?searchparam=searchforthis&searchparam2=searchforthis2` to `/givenresource.php?searchparam=searchforthis&searchparam2=searchforthis2`

This checks that the query string starts `searchparam` and the entire query string is then copied to the *substitution* (target URL):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchparam=
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: The default search parameters in the specs we received use "_id" as the parameter. So the _ is intentional. Also, the givenresource and givenid are not static and vary. Primarily why we want to use redirects.

Comment: Ah OK, but it's presumably `?_id=` in that case (you need a `?` in there somewhere). Lowercase "id"? - you used UPPERCASE in the question? Is `givenid` numeric only or alphanumeric? Or something else?

Comment: Does the query string in the second rewrite need to be validated in any way? At the moment it just makes sure that it starts `searchparam=`.